# Documentation for SKEW.P

Tags: worksheet-function, documentation

I think the formula for population skewness from photo [here](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/skew-p-function-76530a5c-99b9-48a1-8392-26632d542fcb) is wrong.

I think correct formula is [this](https://ibb.co/mCvrv2q).

Am I right?

[EDIT]

1. Please check the example and the result in documentation with both formulas.
2. Please check comments [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/532230).

Answer (score 2):

[Wikipedia Skewness](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skewness)
lists multiple definitions/types of Skewness, meaning that
there is not just one such definition.

Yours seems to fit
[Pearson's moment coefficient of skewness](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skewness#Pearson%27s_moment_coefficient_of_skewness),
but there are other formulations.

This doesn't mean the Microsoft's
[SKEW.P function](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/skew-p-function-76530a5c-99b9-48a1-8392-26632d542fcb)
is wrong, it's just another type of Skewness.

Going deeper into the differences between Microsoft's
formulation and yours should perhaps get better answers on
our sister site of
[Cross Validated](https://stats.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: I edited my question.

Comment: It maybe be unlikely that the *implementation* is wrong, but the documentation definitely is (that's not even a valid formula, there's a dashed line square in it that's just some Microsoft equation editor placeholder, it means nothing).

Comment: That's a documentation gaff, the dotted square should have been "N". The formula wasn't yet finished when it was pasted into the page. See [this link](https://wiki.documentfoundation.org/Documentation/Calc_Functions/SKEWP).

Comment: @harrymc That one's wrong too! The N should go on top of the sigma, not to the right of it.

Comment: They all use lousy equation editors. The documentation writers for large companies are not statisticians so they make mistakes. One has to make allowances, as their intentions are good.